# python import executes local files

Tags: python

Hi i am new to python and i want to understand the following in detail:

I've written a script, say 'foo.py', which uses the python html parser, i.e.

```
#!/usr/lib/python
from html.parser import HTMLParser    # <-- executes ./tokenize.py ?!
...
```

Accidentally, in the current directory lies an other python script called 'tokenize.py'. By executing foo.py, the import line triggers tokenize.py to be executed as well. I guess the local directory has priority and the html.parser module has a tokenize.py as well...

But what exactly happens?

And what is a proper way to avoid such conflicts in the future?

thx

EDIT: I run python 3.3.2

Comment: What version of Python are you running? Try this before your imports :`from __future__ import absolute_import`

Comment: I don't yet understand this relative and absolute import business, but `from __future__ import absolute_import` doesn't change anything.

Comment: Sorry @gmoktop that was before you said python3.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, [modules in the current directory are loaded first](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path).

The proper way to avoid this is always importing your modules by full name. In your case, in `html.parser` you should import `tokenize` like this:

```
from html.parser import tokenize
```

Instead of:

```
import tokenize
```

If `html.parser` is an external module which you don't control, just rename your `tokenize.py` to something else, e.g.:

```
from html.parser import tokenize as ext_tokenize
```

Comment: Ok, I see the point, but I don't import `tokenize` at all. How should I know what `HTMLParser` pulls in?

Comment: @gmoktop If you got this error it means that `HTMLParser` indeed imports `tokenize`. You can always look at its source code and validate this.

Comment: Ok, i did some search. The only solutions I found are 
1) edit the module search sys.path
2) make sure that there are no name conflicts
Both are not very satisfactory..